# Cannot understand the output of symbolicate crash log of an Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, symbolicatecrash

I am trying to send a Xamarin.Forms application onto the Apple App Store.
I've built it from Visual Studio, Ad-Hoc with the LLVM compiler. Saved the output on the mac onto another folder (.app, .ipa, .dSYM).

Now, Apple refuses it since there is an issue with IPv6 with the app and they are attaching a crash log to the issue. When I try to symbolicate the crash log, I don't have anything relevent to my app in the output, only thing I could relate to, is the Main class, but it tells me a line number that does not exist.

Here is a part of the symbolicate output : http://pastebin.com/PjhCuTgV

Is there something I am missing, or a better way to debug iOS code from Xamarin ?

--

Edit : I managed to get a better crashlog :

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x193fb51b8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x1929ec55c objc_exception_throw + 52
2   UIKit                                0x19a618490 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 780
3   UIKit                                0x19a0eca70 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 92
4   UIKit                                0x199ed5320 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
5   UIKit                                0x19a0eb6e8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1364
6   UIKit                                0x19a100104 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3139 + 44
7   UIKit                                0x19a0e87ec -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 164
8   FrontBoardServices                   0x195b8b92c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 32
9   FrontBoardServices                   0x195b8b798 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 172
10  FrontBoardServices                   0x195b8bb40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
11  CoreFoundation                       0x193f62b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                       0x193f624a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 520
13  CoreFoundation                       0x193f600a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 800
14  CoreFoundation                       0x193e8e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
15  UIKit                                0x199ece7b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 604
16  UIKit                                0x199ec9534 UIApplicationMain + 204
17  MyApp                                0x100bb22e4 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (<unknown>:1)
18  MyApp                                0x100b20c4c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr (UIApplication.cs:79)
19  MyApp                                0x100b20c0c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
20  MyApp                                0x1001fb444 MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ (<unknown>:1)
21  MyApp                                0x10047de54 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 240
22  MyApp                                0x100116434 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2551)
23  MyApp                                0x10017a658 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2820)
24  MyApp                                0x10017d240 do_exec_main_checked (object.c:2978)
25  MyApp                                0x100100198 mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1049)
26  MyApp                                0x1001fadd0 xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:485)
27  MyApp                                0x1014232dc main (main.arm64.m:159)
28  libdyld.dylib                        0x192e715b8 start + 0
```

Comment: I have seen many rejection reports from Apple that site an IPv6 compatibility issue where the issue really has nothing to do with IPv6. Just a heads up. In one case, the app was crashing at startup due to a missing permission description, but Apple rejected stating the app was not IPv6 compatible. Also that crash log is not symbolicated at all. See this post for how to symbolicate a crash report: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/

Comment: I have seen this post, and I have followed everystep shown in this blogpost. I've seen other methods to symbolicate a crashlog and never got anymore details... Also, I've checked the permission descriptions and I am using only the ones declared.

Comment: I have manager to get a better output from the crashlog using HockeyApp. Not sure why, I verified all UUID, from the crashlog, .app, .dSYM, from mdfind or dwarfdump. See origin post for the updated log. Thanks

Comment: It looks like the Obj-C exception is thrown when trying to load a storyboard. You should not have a Main.storyboard fro a X.Forms app, so look in your Info.plist for the iOS project and make sure you do not have a Main interface file set. But this is just a guess based on what I see. Could be an issue in your Launch.storyboard as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did have the Main story board values setted to the LaunchScreen. Tried without those values, still did not work. Found something else and the review passed, will write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the app was taking too much time starting. In this case, the crash log should have the exception code of : 0x8badf00d. According to the Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

```
The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.
```

In my case, the log had the exception code of 0x0000000000000000, which just says an unhandled obj-c code exception. Apple provided no help to find that issue, since on our devices it was working properly on TestFlight. Most I could get them to help me from understanding their environment was : "I pressed the icon and it crashed".

What I did to fix my application was to reduce as much as possible the initial loading time, navigate into a "loading view", which contains only an ActivityMonitor. When the app was fully initialized, I would then navigate to the proper view.